# Defining a "flat" OpenAPI document schema?

Tags: json, openapi

I'm trying to document a micros service using OpenAPI 3.0
The service returns Json that has any field name and can contain any of array, string, number, true, false, null, but **not** object. Strings could contain an ISO date. There are only very few known field names (e.g. "@id")

Sample:

```
   { "@unid" : "a34", "color" : "blue", "value" : 42, "active" : true }
```

Invalid sample:

```
   { "@unid" : "b55",
     "shape" : "square",
     "params" : { "value" : 42, "active" : true }
   }
```

So my first try was:

```yaml
title: Root Type for Document
description: A generic document
type: object
properties:
    '@unid':
        description: Primary key
        type: string
    '@created':
        format: date-time
        description: Document creation dateTime as ISO date
        type: string
    '@size':
        format: int32
        description: Storage size on backend
        type: integer
    '@unread':
        description: Did user accnowledge having read it
        type: boolean
additionalProperties:
    anyOf:
        -
            type: string
        -
            type: boolean
        -
            type: integer
        -
            format: date-time
            type: string
example:
    '@unid': EA219565FC07ADC600258695004FCE92
    '@created': '2021-03-11T14:31:42Z'
    '@size': 31
    '@unread': false
    Color: Red
    form: SampleForm
    Cost: 31.3
    Active: true
    lastaccessed: '2021-03-11T14:31:42.000Z'
```

I checked the [OpenAPI dictionary spec](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/), it suggested to use:

```yaml
type: object
additionalProperties: true
```

but that would allow for objects.

Am I on the right track? Or is there an easier/correct to say "any name, any value, just not another object" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-OpenAPI 3 compliant way, but OpenAPI 3.1 compliant, is to use the not keyword:

```
type: object
additionalProperties: true
not:
  additionalProperties:
    type: object
```

The logic here is:

- Any additional property is fine
- But not additional properties with type object